# Detect car poistion at specific location in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to detect car postion and direction at that white parking area as in the attached image, i.e the car is exactly on that location and and in that direction. I tried some methods but they are not perfect. How can I do it perfectly?
[image]

Comment: What is a `car` in your program, and what is the code you've tried that doesn't work/what about it doesn't work?

Comment: to get the position, have you tried simply comparing x & y coordinates between the car and the parking space?

Comment: I cannot get plane object position in javascript when i try to display it in Debug.log then it blocks the GUI. The white parking area in above image is actually plane with texture and i want to get compare its position with car position.

Comment: Why can't you get the plane's position? It's as simple as "planeObject.transform.position". What have you tried? Post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try comparing the position of the plane to the position of the car using "GameObject.transform.position".

Alternatively, you could place empty gameobjects in the 4 corners of the parking spot, and then check if the car's position is within the bounds of the 4 gameobject's positions.

Post the code you've already tried, perhaps we can help you fix it.

Comment: The main problem in my code is getting the game object now that is solved. Thanks for your answer. @Murkantilism@Creator

Comment: What do you mean "getting" the gameobject? Accessing it, instantiating it?

Comment: "Accessing game object" as i m new in unity, but now i solved that problem. Thanks @Murkantilism

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the parking spot and car both are same size on x and z position and you can manually place the car on the parking spot in the editor. 
If yes then you just need to match their transform. The following psuedo code may help.

```
bool CheckParking(){
    if(parking.transform.position.x == car.transform.position.x && parking.transform.position.z == car.transform.position.z)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

You do not need to compare the y position, since both parking spot and car will be having different y positions.

If you do not have same sized (in x and z) car and parking spot, then you can add extra conditions for margins in x and z.